# applying a function to groups matching multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to add a new column to my df that is simply my function *hardfunct*  applied to 'values' where the row is 'hardness'. I would then like that value to fill all the rows in that column for the matching 'site' and 'dates'. How do I fill the rest of the rows? I've tried using summarise, rowwise and mutate. Sample data is below.

```
site=c(rep("River A",4),rep("River B",4))
dates=as.Date(c("01/01/2001","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001"),  format = "%m/%d/%Y")
param=c("lead","hardness","mercury","cadmium","lead","hardness","mercury","cadmium")
value=c("0.2","45","0.9","1.2","0.5","1800","0.6","0.8")

df=data.frame(site,param,dates,value)

hardfunct=function(x){
if (x>=400) {
print(400)
} else if (x<=25) {
print(25)
} else {
return(x)}
}

#######Trying to use group_by and mutate

df %>% group_by(site,dates) %>% 
mutate(New_Hardness=sapply(df[df$param=="hardness","value"],hardfunct))
```

#### This is what data frame with the new column should look like

```
site      param     dates     value New_Hardness
River A   lead      1/1/2001    0.2   45
River A   hardness  1/1/2001    45    45
River A   mercury   1/1/2001    0.9   45
River A   cadmium   1/1/2001    1.2   45
River B   lead      5/8/2001    0.5   400
River B   hardness  5/8/2001    1800  400
River B   mercury   5/8/2001    0.6   400
River B   cadmium   5/8/2001    0.8   400
```

Comment: After correcting variable format `df$value <- as.numeric(as.character(value))` then `with(df, pmax(25, pmin(400, value)))` should work...? Oh, never mind, didn't notice the "fill all the rows in that column for the matching 'site' and 'dates'" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
site=c(rep("River A",4),rep("River B",4))
dates=as.Date(c("01/01/2001","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","01/01/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001","05/08/2001"),  format = "%m/%d/%Y")
param=c("lead","hardness","mercury","cadmium","lead","hardness","mercury","cadmium")
value=c("0.2","45","0.9","1.2","0.5","1800","0.6","0.8")

df=data.frame(site,param,dates,value, stringsAsFactors = F)

hardfunct=function(x){
  if (x>=400) {
    return(400)
  } else if (x<=25) {
    return(25)
  } else {
    return(x)}
}

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(site, dates) %>%
  mutate(New = hardfunct(as.numeric(value[param == "hardness"]))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   site    param    dates      value   New
#   <chr>   <chr>    <date>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1 River A lead     2001-01-01 0.2      45
# 2 River A hardness 2001-01-01 45       45
# 3 River A mercury  2001-01-01 0.9      45
# 4 River A cadmium  2001-01-01 1.2      45
# 5 River B lead     2001-05-08 0.5     400
# 6 River B hardness 2001-05-08 1800    400
# 7 River B mercury  2001-05-08 0.6     400
# 8 River B cadmium  2001-05-08 0.8     400
```

Note that you have to change the `print` in your function to `return`, otherwise you also a get a printed value before your dataframe output.

Also note that you need to have character variables and not factors, because the `as.numeric` applied to factors will give you different numbers that what you expect.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code, the "New" column returns 45 and 1800 every other row instead of matching your df above @AntoniosK

Comment: Not sure why that happens. Can you clear your workspace and try again?

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use the split/apply/combine strategy.

Note that the `pmax` and `pmin` idea is @Frank's.

```
sp <- split(df, list(df$site, df$dates))
sp <- sp[sapply(sp, function(x) nrow(x) != 0)]
newdf <- lapply(sp, function(DF) {
    DF$New_Hardness <- pmax(25, pmin(400, DF$value[DF$param == "hardness"]))
    DF
})

rm(sp)    # tidy up

newdf <- do.call(rbind, newdf)
row.names(newdf) <- NULL

newdf
#     site    param      dates  value New_Hardness
#1 River A     lead 2001-01-01    0.2           45
#2 River A hardness 2001-01-01   45.0           45
#3 River A  mercury 2001-01-01    0.9           45
#4 River A  cadmium 2001-01-01    1.2           45
#5 River B     lead 2001-05-08    0.5          400
#6 River B hardness 2001-05-08 1800.0          400
#7 River B  mercury 2001-05-08    0.6          400
#8 River B  cadmium 2001-05-08    0.8          400
```

Comment: My actual data set is relatively large. Using the split method keeps freezing R.